# Why isn't my molecular fabricator crafting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-applied-energistics

I've set up a recipe in my molecular fabricator, but started crafting without all the necessary ingredients.

My crafting monitor looks like this:

[image]

I've added the processors, but the crafting does not resume. Is there some way to make it resume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a job resume after adding missing materials, Shift+left click the missing item in this interface. It will clear it from the missing list, and crafting will resume.

Comment: Is there some way I can get a redstone signal if crafting is blocked?

Comment: @fredley I'd like to say no, or at least not currently, but I'm not certain of that, and I will see.

Comment: I have found no way to emit any kind of signal when crafting is blocked. I have also found inconsistent data on crafting becoming stuck in this manner, but I can confirm that shift+left clicking will clear the sticking point if materials are available. This might be considered a bug and change, but I can't say for certain.